# Apex Code to send Email Alert to record type

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

How to write apex code for leads - would like to trigger an email template to a particular record type user.

When the custom field input box has been filled with the correct contact name (who the lead should be forwarded to) this should trigger an email to be sent to that user. With some lead field information.

These users do not have a Salesforce license currently. Help Pls

Comment: Maybe have a look on http://salesforce.stackexchange.com

Comment: And please be more clear in your explanation (whether you ask it here or on SFSE)